# (JasperReports) JRExporterParameter.FONT_MAP is missing (how to replace?)

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I'm moving from JasperReports 4.0.0 to JasperReports 6.1.0

I used to do:

```
Map<FontKey, PdfFont> fontMap = new HashMap<>();
fontMap.put(new FontKey("SansSerif", true, true), new PdfFont("ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true));
fontMap.put(new FontKey("Helvetica", false, false), new PdfFont("ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true));
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.FONT_MAP, fontMap);
```

But the property FONT_MAP does not exist anymore (same for class: **FontKey + PdfFont**)

How can i achieve the same with JasperReports 6.1.0?